# Ubuntu 16.04.1 is very slow after installation

Tags: performance

I'm new to Linux. Yesterday I removed Windows 10 from my laptop to install Ubuntu as I heard that it is much more efficient. It took me a day to understand how to install it. Now it is working very slow. When I start my laptop it takes almost 5-10 minutes to display the login screen. When the computer boots it asks for cleaning some files. I am new to Ubuntu and don't know much about it.

Hardware:

- Dell-Vostro-3558
- i5 (5th gen)
- 8GB RAM

Questions:

- Why is Ubuntu running that slow?
- What can I do to optimize the current situation?

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu. So what is your actual question right now?

Comment: What hardware / laptop model do you have ?

Comment: Dell-Vostro-3558

Comment: I want to know why is ubuntu working slow on my laptop though it is i-5 fifth generation with 8gb of RAM

Comment: The startup is extremely slow.

Comment: A possible reason could be missing or better non-optimal graphic drivers. Please make a screenshot of the 'Additional Driver' gui (Software & Updates -> Tab: Additional Drivers) and add it to your question.

Comment: Please add the output of the 'cleaning files' activity on startup as well to your question. This might help.

Comment: It could be because you're running a pre-release version. Install 16.04.

Comment: There are no additional drivers @dufte

Comment: @Zacharee1 installed 16.04.1

Comment: @IbrahimIqbal then why have you titled and tagged your question with 16.10?

Comment: There was no tag available for 16.04.1 @Zacharee1

Comment: @IbrahimIqbal so use 16.04 not a completely separate version. That still doesn't explain the title.

Comment: I've edited. My bad @Zacharee1

Comment: @IbrahimIqbal were you using 16.10 or 16.04?

Comment: Are you really on 16.04? I ask because if some one answers and something goes wrong it could cause you some big issues and as you misrepresented your version we would not be responsible. Also, cleaning what files exactly? That info would be great.

Comment: Please don't tag with a specific version unless you *know* your question is only about that version and no other. You should just mention the version you use in the question itself.

Comment: @terdon If I'm using 16.04 you're saying I can't use that tag until I've installed every other Ubuntu version to ensure the problem isn't there too????

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix no, I'm saying [you should generally not use version tags at all unless it happens to be an issue specific to that version](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7245/85695). If you're not sure, don't use the tag. Version tags are next to useless anyway.